# Rounding the scientific notation of BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I would like to print a `BigDecimal` in scientific notation so that the there are, say, 5 digits after the decimal point. For example: `-3.12345E-51`, `9.12345E100`

`.setScale()` does not work in this case, because I don't know in advance the exponent of number in scientific notation. Moreover, `BigDecimal` doesn't seem to have a `getExponent()` method.

What's the best way to achieve this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to print numbers in specified format:

```
    BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(-3.12345E-51);
    DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.#####E0");
    System.out.println(format.format(bigDecimal));
```

Also you can configure count of fraction digits using method [DecimalFormat#setMaximumFractionDigits(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setMinimumFractionDigits%28int%29):

```
    DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0E0");
    format.setMaximumFractionDigits(6);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you! A slightly related question: if I want to have "#" appear some N number of times, where N is a variable, is there a shortcut to express this, or do I have to do a loop where I append "#" N times to a string?

Comment: @blf I have modified answer.